# Is it possible to use HTML Payment buttons solution in Paypal whilst using webhook notifications?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-rest-sdk

I have a website where I'm implementing a subscription payment system.

I would like to use the standard Paypal buttons (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/get_started/).

Instead of IPN, I would like to use the Rest API Webhooks notifications as I think it would be easier to integrate further with my system later on.

Wondering if this is possible or does the standard Paypal buttons only support IPT?

Comment: Webhooks only work with REST.  You'll need to use that if you want to use webhooks.

Comment: @AndrewAngell - thanks, I figured that was the case. Is it possible to use the rest API to look up subscriptions created by HTML payment buttons?